# How to loop though json data and get specific key value

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Here is the data

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "sys": { "id": " 01/03/1997" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "First title",
        "p": "paragraph 1.",
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
      }
    },
    {
        "sys": { "id": "2 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post",
          "p": "paragraph 2",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": { "id": "3 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post 1",
          "p": "paragraph 3",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": { "id": "4 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post 2",
          "p": "paragraph 4",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": { "id": "8 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post 3",
          "p": "paragraph",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to loop though this data on the server side and get a specific key value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.items.length; i++) {
  var currentObject = jsonObj.items[i].fields
  for(var title in currentObject){
          if(currentObject.hasOwnProperty(title)) {
            // console.log(title + ': ' + currentObject[title]);
            // console.log(currentObject[i]);
              // console.log(`${title}`);
              // var pageTitle = currentObject[title];
              // console.log(pageTitle); 
              var pageTitle = currentObject[title];
              console.log(currentObject[title]); 
          }
     }
     console.log(currentObject[title]);
}

fs.appendFile( './public/html/' + `${title}`  + '.html', `file.html`
, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

It keeps outputting

```
First title
paragraph 1.
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
First Blog Post
paragraph 2
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
First Blog Post 1
paragraph 3
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
First Blog Post 2
paragraph 4
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
First Blog Post 3
paragraph
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
{ fields: { file: { url: '../../images/cheap-skateboards.png' } } }
```

and creates a file image.html which is the last key in the array. how can i get the first key the title to output? I want to create a new file on the server with these titles as the file name.

Comment: So you only want the title key right? So you want an array like this: `["First Title", "First Blog Post", "First Blog Post 1", "First Blog Post 2", "First Blog Post 3"]`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it that well, maybe you can clarify, I'm assuming you want the `title` as the key and the `url` as the value, is that it?

then a simple `map` would suffice...

Just be careful, as key's can't have duplicate values, and you might have duplicate titles.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "items": [
    {
      "sys": { "id": " 01/03/1997" },
      "fields": {
        "title": "First title",
        "p": "paragraph 1.",
        "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
      }
    },
    {
        "sys": { "id": "2 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post",
          "p": "paragraph 2",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": { "id": "3 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post 1",
          "p": "paragraph 3",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": { "id": "4 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post 2",
          "p": "paragraph 4",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      },
      {
        "sys": { "id": "8 01/03/1997" },
        "fields": {
          "title": "First Blog Post 3",
          "p": "paragraph",
          "image": { "fields": { "file": { "url": "../../images/cheap-skateboards.png" } } }
        }
      }
  ]
};


var newObject = jsonObj.items.map((x) => {
  const o = {}; // create the object
  o[x.fields.title] = x.fields.image.fields.file.url; // assign the key and value
  return o; // return the new object
});

console.log(newObject); // print
```

then you can simple itinerate through that `newObject` with

```js
Object.keys(newObject).forEach(title => {
    const url = newObject[title]
})
```